# COUNTIF QUERY - formula not working

Tags: excel-formula, countif

I have a `COUNTIF` query where the formula checks columns for specific text. If any one of these columns contain `Missing`, then the value returned should be `NMC InCorrect`, but for some reason the formula is not picking up on this.

Sample data:

```
TASK Dates  TASK Start but No End   TASK Notes Lock WI Notes Lock   NMC Correct?
TASK Dates  Missing                 Missing         Missing         NMC CORRECT
TASK Dates  Missing                 Missing         Missing         NMC CORRECT
Missing     Missing                 Missing         Locked by NMC  NMCINCORRECT
Missing     Missing                 Missing         Locked by NMC  NMCINCORRECT
```

Here is my current formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(M2:P2,"Missing")=4,"NMC INCORRECT","NMC CORRECT")`
```

As stated above, it should return `NMC INCORRECT`  for line 2 above, because that line has `TASK Dates` and not `Missing` in its 1st column.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want may be:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(M2:P2,"Missing")>0,"NMC INCORRECT","NMC CORRECT")
```

Rather than test for a count of 4 `Missing` in the same row it tests for any number of `Missing` in that row (any quantity more than none at all).